# Bwa-meme indexing

Tags: indexing, path, fasta

I'm running this command:
docker run quay.io/biocontainers/bwa-meme:1.0.5--hd03093a_0 bwa-meme index <.fasta>

It displays: bwa_index: not such file or directory but I'm sure is the correct path.
I've also tried to specify the full path.

Someone knows why bwa-meme could not recognise and open .fasta file?

Kind regards,
Fra